# Iterate through NSMutableDictionary and change value

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

Thanks for any help with the following:

I'm loading the following JSON data ..

```
(
    {
    name = Facilities;
    versiondate = "1972-01-01";
},
    {
    name = Services;
    versiondate = "1972-01-01";
},
    {
    name = ThingsToDo;
    versiondate = "1972-01-01";
}
)
```

into the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:updateData options:kNilOptions error:&errorString];
```

I am then trying to iterate over the Dictionary and trying to change the *versiondate* to today's date. I have spent over two hours trying to do this ... and no luck! I'm fighting with trying to also understand MutableCopies etc. I'm relatively new at this ...

So, I'm trying the following:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *item in dictionary)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newdict = [item mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"I have item as: %@",newdict);
    NSLog(@"I have the date as: %@", [newdict objectForKey:@"versiondate"]);
    [newdict setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"versiondate"];
    NSLog(@"I now have the date as: %@", [newdict objectForKey:@"versiondate"]);
    NSLog(@"I have item as: %@",newdict);
    item = newdict;
}

NSLog(@"New Dictionary now becomes: %@", dictionary);
```

And ignoring the NSLog stuff, I'm having no luck. I'm just trying to change the *versiondate* to today's date and then save it for each *versiondate*. Sigh.

Any help to tell me where my "obvious" error is would be appreciated. I'm declaring item as NSMutableDictionary ... so why do I have to then define *newdict*? And once I've updated the value, how do I "save" this back into my original dictionary?

Comment: PS. The item = newdict doesn't work ... I just threw it in there for additional feelings of ineptitude.

Comment: @alpz, that's not true. If it were, in fact, a mutable dictionary, setting a new value for an existing key would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want mutable dictionaries and arrays when you deserialize the JSON, pass the option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`. Otherwise, what comes out is *not* mutable. And treating it as such will result in the `NSInternalInconsistencyException` you're seeing.

You can create mutable copies of the sub-dictionaries, as in the code you show, but that doesn't change the original top-level container's contents. (And assigning the copy back to the original variable at the bottom of your loop accomplishes exactly nothing.)

Comment: You're a legend! And, what's more than irritating is ... I used to have the options set as NSJSONReadingMutableContainers! Solved. And two hours of my life gone!

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newdict = [item mutableCopy];
```

you are creating a *copy* of the `item`, and then modifying the copy. Instead, just modify `item` directly:

```
[item setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"versiondate"];
```

I see what you're trying to do with `item = newdict` but that would just change the object that the local pointer `item` points to, and wouldn't change the *actual* item in `dictionary`.

Comment: I tried that originally ... but this is the error I'm getting:

2012-09-27 14:05:29.617 SpaceHotelApp[9643:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: Oh, well if your dictionary doesn't actually contain mutable dictionaries, then using `for (NSMutableDictionary *item` is lying to the compiler, and you'll get all kinds of bad behaviour. Use this in combination with @SixtenOtto's answer and you'll get what you need.